# Having troubles with smart pointers and vectors, constant crashing

Tags: c++, tree, smart-pointers, raw-pointer, merkle-tree

So im trying to build a merkle tree from a vector of strings, first convert all the strings to the MerkleNodes and then form their parents, building the tree upside down.
But it seems to be an issue when i push all the nodes to the vector in the first FOR loop, because i cant access to them. I ve debug it and that seems to be the problem altough i dont know what else i can do, actually I first try with raw pointers but get the same issue.

```
  inline std::shared_ptr<MerkleNode> AddLeaf(const std::string &vright, const std::string &vleft) {
     std::shared_ptr<merkle::MerkleNode> right (new MerkleNode (vright));
     std::shared_ptr<merkle::MerkleNode> left (new MerkleNode (vleft));
     return std::make_shared<merkle::MerkleNode>(std::move(left), std::move(right));
 }

 std::shared_ptr<merkle::MerkleNode> Build(const std::vector<std::string> &values) {
     std::vector< std::shared_ptr<merkle::MerkleNode> > nodes(values.size());

     for (const auto &value: values) {
         nodes.push_back(std::make_shared<merkle::MerkleNode>(value));
     }
// I verify that the values are correct and that inmediatly after the push_back i can access to the nodes. 
//But in the second FOR loop with iterators i get ERROR -1073741819 (0xC0000005) when accessing the elemnts.
     std::vector< std::shared_ptr<merkle::MerkleNode> >::iterator it;
     while (nodes.size() > 1) {
         if (nodes.size() % 2 != 0) nodes.push_back(std::move(nodes.back()));
         std::vector<std::shared_ptr<merkle::MerkleNode> > new_nodes;

         for (it = nodes.begin(); it != nodes.end(); it += 2) {
             //std::shared_ptr<merkle::MerkleNode> h(it->get());

             auto temp = std::move(AddLeaf((*it)->hash(),(*(it+1))->hash()));
             new_nodes.push_back(std::move(temp));
         }
         //nodes = new_nodes;

     }
     return std::move(std::shared_ptr<MerkleNode>(nodes[0].get()));
 }
```

Comment: `std::move(std::shared_ptr<MerkleNode>(nodes[0].get()));` is a recipe for death. The pointer from the ctor argument is already owned by one smart pointer control block; now you're standing it up in another. And your sizing on `nodes` is wrong anyway.  `std::vector< std::shared_ptr<merkle::MerkleNode> > nodes(values.size());` creates a vector of `values.size()` empty smart pointers, then just pushes new ones on the *end* of that sequence. From what I see that should be `std::vector< std::shared_ptr<merkle::MerkleNode> > nodes;`

Comment: `nodes.push_back(std::move(nodes.back()));` smells too. You are using move semantics instead of copying.

Comment: Mauricio there is a lot going on in the few lines you posted, I got really confused to the point of not being able to help. There are (1) pointers (2) moves (3) vector ops.  I would suggest to give a step back and remove one of them. Let the shared pointer do its job and perhaps remove all std::move. If you were using unique_ptr you could not do this but with shared_ptr  you can. You might get a performance penalty but you will remove one term of this equation. Once you figure out what's wrong, you can carefully put it back.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @HenriqueBucher You're right, i just get confuse and tried everything i saw on oter examples, i'll try to simplify and update! thanks

Comment: Move semantics is more ideology than a real solution. It is optional. If you use shared pointers you do not need it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Treat `shared_ptr` as a value type i.e. pass the pointer itself by copy, in order to propagate ownership, which is what this smart pointer is intended for.

Also, `move` shouldn't be used when returning because it interferes with compiler optimizations. The compiler knows that the return item should be moved into a new scope (return value optimization).

For more details, see this ISO CPP guideline about move: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es56-write-stdmove-only-when-you-need-to-explicitly-move-an-object-to-another-scope

Speaking for the code sample, you would probably benefit from moving large strings into new owners, if they're not used elsewhere after moving.

Answer (score -5):

Just use RAW pointers and FOR EACH, iterators and smart pointers just too much thinking...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).